# Difference between calling a service method in drupal 8

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I want to know what difference does it make when i call a service this way :

```
$service = \Drupal::service('myservice.method');
$service->methodNameInService();
```

or this way (Dependency Injecton)

```
 public function __construct(MyService $myService) {
+    $this->myService = $myService;
   }

public function test() {
    // Call function from service 
    $this->myService->methodNameInService();

}
```

Is this better for performance or is it just only the right way and has it zero effect on performance or something else?

Comment: From the class level you should use dependency injection and not the static service container. From procedural code, the static service is the only option you have.

Comment: Also, strive to type hint interfaces instead of concrete classes when possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency Injection has several advantages when you try to create test for your code, and follow the Single Responsibility Principle.

Really, the second reason is a consequence than the first: "The code is testeable because follow the SRP"

Furthermore, IDEs can recognize better the class type (and create autocompletes, f.e.) if the class is defined using DI. In a normal IDE, $service defined in `$service = \Drupal::service('myservice.method');` has a unknown class.

In some places you cannot use DI (fe. in a .module) and you need to use the static load.